# k means for segmenting time series

Tags: r, time-series, k-means, timeseries-segmentation

Now, I am trying to understand how to segment a multivariate time series using k- means. I understand that the basic concept is to use centroids of segments rather than centroids of data points and minimize the residual error.

But what does a 'segment' mean in this context? How can I use a vector of data points as a segment or number of segments?

I use R so if you could provide example code or link to time series segmentation using k-means it would be really nice.

Comment: No, Kmeans clustering does not work on dependent/time series data. Try searching keyword "time series clustering" you will get some good techniques. DTW + Hierarchical clustering is a popular method for time series clustering/segmentation.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide a laser-like focus per the rules of the community? You seem to be asking, "What is a segment as is referred to in segmented regression?".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think k-means is a good approach here, as it is not aimed for time-series data and especially of higher dimensionality. You should look into something that takes into account the time component, like hidden markov models, autoregressive models or a combination of both for example.

Comment: Isn't this the same thing forecaster just mentioned in a comment?

Comment: Actually, if you hover over the time answered, you will see that we both posted at *almost* the same time (16:56 mine, 16:59 @forecaster 's answer). Weird? Totally.